# TestNG @RunWith from JUnit

Tags: junit, testng

I'm moving from JUnit to TestNG.

My classes already have a constructor so I've added a zero-args constructor as requested, now I notice that the @RunWith is using org.junit.runner.

I presume I need to comment out `import org.junit.runner.RunWith;` but what is the TestNG equivalent I need to use?

Thanks.

Comment: `@RunWith` doesn't exist with TestNG. The default TestNG runner should be enough. What junit runner did you use?

Comment: Hi, Ah ok, i just realised - was using 4.11.
So my issue is I have a constructor that injects the following
How do i now do this in a @Before
`@Inject
  public DigitalTests(Logger log, WcConfigManager config,
    WebSessionFactory sessionFactory) {
   super(log, config, sessionFactory);
  }`

Comment: You should update the question with the more details/example as possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33919644/junit-to-testng-constructor-with-args

Answer (score 6):

Extend your test class from

```
org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.
```

It is the equivalent of Junit `@RunWith`.