# JUnit to TestNG Constructor with Args

Tags: junit, testng

I'm moving from JUnit to TestNG. TestNG asks for a zero args constructor that I have provided, however my test class requires a constructor where I am passing some config to the test:

```
@DataProvider(filename = "DataSheet.xlsx", sheet = "DigitalTestsMain")

public class DigitalTests extends AbstractTests{

        @Inject
        public DigitalTests(Logger log, WcConfigManager config,
                                WebSessionFactory sessionFactory) {
            super(log, config, sessionFactory);
        }

        public DigitalTests() { 
        }


        @Test
        public void myAutomationTest() throws Exception { .... }
```

As TestNG use a zero args constructor I do I pass these values in, would that be in a `@Before`?

Comment: Could you show us `AbstractTests` too?

Comment: Does the config apply to all tests in the class?

Comment: Yes it is. I just need an example of how whats done in the constructor with arguments is done.

Answer (score 0):

TestNG supports [@Inject from Guice](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#guice-dependency-injection), but I've never try it on constructor. You should try by adding the appropriate `@Guice` on the class.

[Factories](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#factories) are antoher way to pass parameters to test constructor.

Depending on your `AbstractTests`, maybe `@BeforeX/AfterX` will be the best solution.

Comment: The AbstractTests is quite a long file, what exactly would you need to know.
The BeforeX sounds appealing, would it work like this:
`@BeforeTest
  public void doBeforeSuite() {

  Logger log = super.getLog();
  WcConfigManager config = super.getConfig();
  WebSessionFactory sessionFactory = super.getSessionFactory();
  }`

Comment: I need to understand why the super class has constructor params and if it is possible to remove them.
And be careful, `@BeforeTest` of JUnit => `@BeforeMethod` of TestNG.

Comment: It is required - it handles things like logging success and failures, proving common used functions and handling logic of the @DataProvider at the start of each test class.